# Converting from Text file to class objects

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am struggling with one thing and finally I decided to ask for help here.

As a title says I have a text file with contains this:

> Wulkan 4487.9361 False
>
> Merkury 56847.1906 True
>
> Wenus 107710.46639999999 True
>
> Ziemia 149597.87 True
>
> Mars 227388.7624 True
>
> Faeton 403914.249 False
>
> Jowisz 777908.924 True
>
> Saturn 1425667.7011 True
>
> Uran 2870783.1253 True
>
> Neptun 4496911.9722 True
>
> Pluton 5906123.9076 True

And now I am trying to convert it to objects with 3 arguments something like

```
class Planets:
    def __init__(self, name, dist, real):
```

As far I did that:

```
with open('planety.txt', 'r') as file:
    x = file.read()


for z in x.split("\n"):
    if z:
        planets = z.split(" ")
```

How can I exact each list that I get in varible planets into objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way:

```
class Planets:
    def __init__(self, name, dist, real):
        self.name = name

with open('planety.txt', 'r') as file:
    x = file.read()

planets = []
for z in x.split("\n"):
    if z:
        planet = Planets(*z.split())
        planets.append(planet)

for planet in planets:
    print(planet.name)
```

`*` unpacks list recieved from `z.split()` into three arguments to `Planets.__init__`

Comment: But how can I create each object In class Planets? To have separate object that will contain arguments for each Planet.

Comment: So, `planets` is a list of `Planets` objects, ech object contains arguments for each planet described in the text file.

Comment: Yeah I can see it now. Thanks alo :)

Comment: Glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The Approach you are taking to solve this problem is a little bit tricky here is how I did that

```
import csv

_storage = {}

class Planets:
    def __init__(self, name, dist, real):
        self.name = name

with open('doc.txt') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=' ')
    for row in reader:
        if not len(row) == 0:
            name, dist, real = row
            _storage[name] = Planets(name, dist, real)
```

Now you can get any object with planet name

Answer (score 0):

Python has a typing.NamedTuple class. In Python ≥ 3.6, you can use the [`typing.NamedTuple`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/typing.html?highlight=namedtuple#typing.NamedTuple) class as follows:

```
from typing import NamedTuple

class Planet(NamedTuple):
    name: str
    dist: float
    real: bool

planets = []
with open('planets.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        name, dist, real = line.rstrip().split()
        planets.append(Planet(name=name, dist=float(dist), real=(real == 'True')))

for p in planets:
    print(p)

p = planets[0]
print(p.name, p.dist, p.real)
```

**Output:**

```
Planet(name='Wulkan', dist=4487.9361, real=False)
Planet(name='Merkury', dist=56847.1906, real=True)
Planet(name='Wenus', dist=107710.46639999999, real=True)
Planet(name='Ziemia', dist=149597.87, real=True)
Planet(name='Mars', dist=227388.7624, real=True)
Planet(name='Faeton', dist=403914.249, real=False)
Planet(name='Jowisz', dist=777908.924, real=True)
Planet(name='Saturn', dist=1425667.7011, real=True)
Planet(name='Uran', dist=2870783.1253, real=True)
Planet(name='Neptun', dist=4496911.9722, real=True)
Planet(name='Pluton', dist=5906123.9076, real=True)
Wulkan 4487.9361 False
```